# Why doesn't a hyperlink in Excel translate properly?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have an Excel VBA that creates a hyperlink in the sheet to post a question to my Amazon seller account.

The hyperlink ends up in the form:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/productsearch?q=899455410140","Click")
```

However, when you click the hyperlink, the URL that appears in Firefox is:

```
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/productsearch?_encoding=UTF8&q=899455410140
```

Now, I can tell that Amazon appears to be reformatting the request, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it would reformat the url with a double domain, which is obviously causing a 404 error.

Does anyone have a reason why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. The link works fine for me in IE.

Comment: All looks fine in Chrome & FireFox for me too.  The URL I get is this - but that is because it wants me to authenticate.  https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/sign-in/sign-in.html?destination=https%3A%2F%2Fsellercentral.amazon.com%2Fhz%2Fproductsearch%3Fq%3D899455410140